# Jquery ui MultiSelect IE 8 issue

Tags: jquery-ui, multi-select

Using the latest [Jquery UI Multiselect](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) it works fine in firefox, chrome

but in IE8 the options are blank as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsCQv.jpg)

I am using the following libraries
jquery-1.7.2.min.js
jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js

Any ideas, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it,
There is an [issue](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1641) with the way you add the options to a list in JQuery in IE 8
I was using

```
$('#foldersBUSelect').append( new Option(folderName,folderID,false,nowSelected) );
```

when I should be doing the following which IE 8 likes

```
$("#foldersBUSelect").append( "<option selected='selected' value='" + folderID + "'>" + folderName + "</option>" );
```