# Jquery multiselect map function giving an error in ie8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multi-select

I have used the Jquery multiselect functionality in my application.By using map function getting the selected items.

```
appNames = $.map($("select").multiselect("getChecked"), function (item) {
              return item.value;
          });
```

the above working fine in IE9.But ie 8 getting the below error.

```
"Object doesn't support this property or method"
```

For that I tried like `JQuery.map` and `_map` function instead of map but not able to get this.
I should support in IE8.please tell me how to resolve the above issue.I am trying for this from last day..

please any one help me out...

Thanks,

Comment: maybe helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461685/javascript-functions-dont-work-in-ie8-when-passed-as-parameters or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304370/jquery-ui-multiselect-ie-8-issue

Comment: try adding <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> in head section of your html page

Comment: what is $("select").multiselect("getChecked"), what is getChecked is it id or class name ?